# Are questions about publishing music off topic?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about publishing(sharing) music ok?

The Question:
Is it a bad practice to create a music album with different genres but a same "theme" (ex: about nature) to be shared on say soundcloud,bandcamp etc ?.. ( Say the album has different pop,new age,jazzy,electronic songs rather than songs of one particular genre)

Comment: I don't think they are off-topic _per se_, but it may depend on your particular question. Could you be more specific? Maybe write a draft of your true question as a part of this meta question?

Comment: Business and legal concerns are off-topic ... agreed with the above that it would be useful to see the particular question(s) you have in mind.

Comment: I have added the question itself

Answer (score 2):

The specific question you posted *might* be opinion based (thus off topic).

I don't know for sure, but someone (like me) would say that it would be good to post an album with many different genres.

Someone else though, might say the different.

Comment: yeah I think this is subjective. but I wondered if there is a "rule" as we( I ) never find such albums